# React Native - i want to push new item in a previous array like concate or push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, concatenation, asyncstorage

I tried the following, where the country is the new item I want to push/add to the pre-existing countries using text input and concat to previous array data like this.

**e.g.**

```
 saveData = async () => {
       
        try {
            let countries = AsyncStorage.getItem('countries');
            AsyncStorage.setItem('countries', countries.concat(this.state.country));
            alert('Data successfully saved')

            console.log('countries',countries)                      
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e)
        }
        
    }
```

//I tried Many Solutions..

var countries = await AsyncStorage.getItem('countries');
AsyncStorage.setItem('countries', countries += JSON.stringify(country));

//**my output is like this**
**e.g : "name""email""address"**

means no comma no bracket like arrays

**i want output like this e.g  ['name','email','address']**

I tried many solutions but I did not get results. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You might not be setting as array to the asyncstorage.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage can only store `string` data. It is pointed out in the documentation. [Usage | AsyncStorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/)

> Async Storage can only store string data, so in order to store object data you need to serialize it first. For data that can be serialized to JSON you can use JSON.stringify() when saving the data and JSON.parse() when loading the data.

If you want to store array or objects you need to convert and store it as json. And when you want to retrieve that data you just need to parse it and convert it to array again like the docs says.

```js
 saveData = async () => {
    
    try {
        let countries = AsyncStorage.getItem('countries');
        if (countries) countries = JSON.parse(countries);

        AsyncStorage.setItem('countries', JSON.stringify(countries.concat(this.state.country)));

        alert('Data successfully saved')

        console.log('countries', countries)                      
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Also, your current 'countries' data will not work with JSON.parse, so you need to clear it before doing this, or check if it is a json object before continuing to parse/stringify.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works for you

```
const saveData = async () => {
try {
  let countries = AsyncStorage.getItem("countries")
  if (countries) {
    countries = JSON.parse(countries)
    AsyncStorage.setItem(
      "countries",
      JSON.stringify(countries.push(this.state.country))
    )
  } else
    AsyncStorage.setItem("countries", JSON.stringify([this.state.country]))

  alert("Data successfully saved")
  console.log("countries", countries)
} catch (e) {
  alert(e)
}
}
```